# R: Stacked bar chart

Tags: r, data-visualization

I am trying to make a stacked bar chart with each mark in stacked bar corresponds to each row in the data. Each bar corresponds to one hour thus contains 60 marks for each minute. I think barplot function will be used but able to figure it out how? Also there's another column with some values. If there's value in that column I want that value in place of mark. Here's the data i am using

```
RowNo   State   Bar
  1        a    1
  2             1
  3             1
  .
  .
 59             1
 60             1
 61             2
 62             2
 .
 .
 1199           20
 1200           20
 1201      c    21
```

And this is what I am looking for
[image]

Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: it would be helpful with a reproducible example. Try reducing your data to only 5 of the rows you want to plot, and use `dput(data)` to gives us something to work with.

This is not a stacked bar chart, but a heat map (tile or raster plot).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along the line of this:

```
library(tidyverse)
data = expand.grid(list(row = 1:20, bar=1:20)) %>% 
        as_tibble() %>% 
        mutate(state = ifelse(row == 1 & bar == 1, "a", ifelse(row == 20 & bar == 1, "c", NA)),
               row = factor(row))

data  %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x=row, y=bar, fill=state)) + 
    geom_tile(colour="white", width=.6) + 
    geom_text(aes(label=state)) +
    scale_y_reverse()
```

[image]

Comment: This is fantastic! Thanks. One question. Can we give some space between the vertical bars.

Comment: Yes, you can specify the width of the tiles, I added this to the code above. I also made the rows a factor, so that a label for each would be printed.